# show multiple password fields with single checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a code that shows multiple password fields into text.
Here is the approach that I made, my focus is on making the code as short as possible, but it seems like am doing something wrong with the approaches that I took.

**Approach 1:**

```
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementByClassName('.password').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"> Show password
```

Above Approach is working perfectly if I use `getElementById` but not with `getElementByClassName`

**Approach 2:** [fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4LR8IS3F821)

```
Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>
```

The same issue happens with this approach as well if using `getElementByClassName` instead.

Comment: Using the in-browser debugging tools (javascript console) you can easily discover syntax errors like this (mistyped/misnamed function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You should use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName`
- `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. You can use `for` to loop thru

```js
function toogleInput(e) {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName('password');
  for (let item of list) {
    item.type = e.checked ? 'text' : 'password';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toogleInput(this)"> Show password
```

In case you want `jQuery` you can use `attr()`

```js
$(".toggle-password").change(function() {
  $(".password").attr("type", this.checked ? "text" : "password")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="password" class="password">
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-password"> Show password
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is named `getElementsByClassName`. It returns a collection, so you have to loop over the results to apply your transformations to all of them.

**adapted Approach 2:** [fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4LS7FHVXH2X)

```
Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput" class="password">
<input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput2" class="password"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var passwordFields = document.getElementsByClassName("password");
  for (let x of passwordFields) {
    if (x.type === "password") {
      x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

PS: The original question referenced jquery, but since the code contained pure javascript, so does this answer.

Comment: thanks for giving your precious time on this Question sir.